# Rails Mongrel server won't load anything anymore

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongrel

For a long time, I've been using Mongrel to run my rails app. Unfortunately, yesterday, it decided to stop working.

Here's what happens when I try to start up localhost to see my app:

> root@whatever> RAILS_ENV=production script/server

This has always started the Mongrel server, listening to port 3000. I access it by going to localhost:3000.

> Rails 2.3.5 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
>   no page on localhost:3000 will load. It just says "loading..." forever.

The strange part is that it will successfully load about two pages before it decides to never load anything again. If I restart my computer, it may or may not let me load a page or two, but it always just stops loading anything shortly thereafter. Might the server just be incredibly slow, and I only think that it won't load anything? Even still, how would I ascertain that and then fix it?

Naturally, this has made it practically impossible for me to get anything done! Any help is appreciated.

If it matters, I am running Rails 2.3.5, Ruby 1.8.7, Mongrel 1.1.5, on Ubuntu 10.04 LTS.

Comment: Ok-- it definitely actually does load. The problem is that each page load takes several minutes. It's somehow related to my setup because the other developers working out of the same code branch don't face this issue. Any thoughts knowing that?

Comment: Timed it and it took **three minutes thirty seconds** to load a simple page. What could be making it so slow? It's not the code, so how can I make rails or Mongrel just load faster? Keep in mind I did nothing to the Gems or anything that prompted this change in load speed from the other day.

Comment: have you checked the size of your rails log files? my tend to grow to gigabytes.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. In case anyone was ultra-curious, it had nothing to do with either Rails or Mongrel. The user account I was trying to log into had some random SQL query associated with it that was really huge. I don't know why it was there, but trying to log into a certain account was killing everything.

The reason it would occasionally load pages was because that was when I would log in with a different account.

Moral of the story: don't have massive SQL queries associated with random test accounts!